# Parsing result for gold price in JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

So I'm trying to parse this `https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_GC1` and in my code, show nothing but the `last price([4] in data)`. However, not exactly sure how to do it. So far I have this following code

And that's where I'm stuck.

```js
let goldData = new XMLHttpRequest();
goldData.open('GET', 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_GC1', true);
goldData.send();                                                                                  
goldData.onload = function (response) {                                
    let goldResponse = JSON.parse(this.response);
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in a browser or via NodeJS? Are there any errors reported in your console?

Comment: Just use `fetch`, it's a lot easier. Or if you use jQuery, `getJSON` is available.

Comment: trying to write this in atom in order to run in a browser

Comment: never used getJSON before so not exactly sure how to do it here. I've parsed api calls in the past but never anything like this. just not sure how to tell it it's the "last price" bit I want.

Comment: sorry, that just didn't paste right for some reason...will edit. I do have that. but it's not helping if you look at the link, I don't know how to handle that response

Comment: Given how much data that API returns, it would be helpful if you could add a **small** sample to your question and then show exactly what parts of the data you wish to extract. Please also show what you've tried to use and if it's not working, provide any errors that are appearing in your console

Comment: the only thing I've tried really is to use [] which didn't work, I knew it wouldn't(since it's almost the same as using a dot) but tried cause I didn't know what else to do...I'm looking for the last price, of the last day...so that would be dataset then data, then the 5th figure in the first array

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
let goldData = new XMLHttpRequest();
goldData.open('GET', 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/CME_GC1', true);

goldData.onload = function() {
  var lastPrices = [];

  var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var data = response.dataset.data; // get data object from nested object.

  // iterate through the data maps to retrieve all the prices.
  var dataLength = data.length;
  for (var i=0; i<dataLength; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    lastPrices.push(d[4]);
  }

  console.log('lastPrices:', lastPrices);
  // last prices from newest to oldest.
}

goldData.send();
```